# Using RecyclerView for Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

I am using `RecyclerView` with `ParseRecyclerView` I have created an adapter to load the text from parse cloud. I am getting error with view cannot be applied to `PhotoFilterViewHolder`.

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_photo_filter, parent, false);
    return new PhotoFilterViewHolder(view);
}
```

I am using PhotoFilterViewHolder to view items from Parse Cloud

```
public static class PhotoFilterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public PhotoFilterViewHolder(FilterImages post, View view) {
        super(view);
        PlaceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.place_names);
        PlaceName.setText(post.getPlaceName());
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the error! Removed FilterImages post from PhotoFilterViewHolder

```
public static class PhotoFilterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public PhotoFilterViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                FilterImages post = new FilterImages();
                PlaceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.place_names);
                PlaceName.setText(post.getPlaceName());
                ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
            }

            @ParseName("PlaceName")
            public TextView PlaceName;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

return "view" object instead of new PhotoFilterViewHolder(view);